# How to find a topology for $\mathbb{R}$ and a sequence that only converges to $x_1,\ x_2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I'm asked to find  a topology for $\mathbb{R}$ and a sequence that only converges to 1 and 2. Regardless of the solution, is there a way to think of it in a general way? This is, how can find a topology for $\mathbb{R}$ and a sequence that only converges to $x_1,\ x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$?

Thank you

Comment: If I give you a two point set $X=\{x,y\},$ can you come up with a topology on this set so that a sequence in it converges to both $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the topology $\tau=\{A\subset\Bbb R\mid 1,2\in A\text{ or }A\cap\{1,2\}=\emptyset\}$. Then the sequence $1,1,1,1,\ldots$ converges to $1$ and $2$ and only to those two numbers. Can you check it?

Comment: Doesn't this sequence in this topology converge, besides to 1 and 2, to 3, 4... Etc. Since for every open set containing, for instance 3, 1 will also be in the set, thus, the constant sequence will be contained indefinitely?

Comment: Of course. My bad. I've edited my answer.